# Can Zend Framework 1.x disable layouts and rendering on an entire module?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a module called `api` that I would like to flatly disable all rendering and layout and only return JSON. I know I can disable layouts per action in a controller like so:

```
$this->_helper->_layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
```

But how can I do it on the entire `api` module?

---

Solution:
Put this in it's own controller and have all the other controllers extend this:

```
public function preDispatch() {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class My_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->_layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    }
}
class Api_IndexController extends My_Controller_Action
{
     public function viewAction()
     {
        // data to return
        $data = array();
        $this->_helper->json($data);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this inspired my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create plugin and add `preDispatch()` method like this:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    if ($request->getModuleName() === 'messages') {
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('viewRenderer')->setNeverRender(true);
    }
```

From now on module 'messages' will have Layout and view disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a parent controller with your code, that all your module controller will extend.